# Unable to get sso token in outlook add-in app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins

I would get sso token from the backend as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins#pass-the-access-token-to-server-side-code)

In my front I get access token that I pass to back end

```
OfficeRuntime.auth
  .getAccessToken({ allowConsentPrompt: true, allowSignInPrompt: true, forMSGraphAccess: true })
  .then((token) => {
    console.log(token);
    axios
      .get(process.env.REACT_APP_FUNC_ENDPOINT + URLS.GET_GRAPH_DATA, {
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + token },
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        event.completed();
      });
  });
```

In back end side I exchange access token with sso token

```
export async function getAccessToken(authorization: string): Promise<any> {
  if (!authorization) {
    let error = new Error("No Authorization header was found.");
    return Promise.reject(error);
  } else {
    const scopeName: string = process.env.SCOPE || "User.Read";
    const [, /* schema */ assertion] = authorization.split(" ");

    const tokenScopes = (jwt.decode(assertion) as jwt.JwtPayload).scp.split(
      " "
    );
    const accessAsUserScope = tokenScopes.find(
      (scope) => scope === "access_as_user"
    );
    if (!accessAsUserScope) {
      throw new Error("Missing access_as_user");
    }

    const formParams = {
      client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      grant_type: "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
      assertion: assertion,
      requested_token_use: "on_behalf_of",
      scope: [scopeName].join(" "),
    };

    const stsDomain: string = "https://login.microsoftonline.com";
    const tenant: string = "common";
    const tokenURLSegment: string = "oauth2/v2.0/token";
    const encodedForm = form(formParams);
    let tokenResponse;
    try {
      tokenResponse = await axios.post(
        `${stsDomain}/${tenant}/${tokenURLSegment}`,
        encodedForm,
        {
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          },
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

    return tokenResponse.data;
  }
}
```

But I get an error

> 'AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the
> application with ID '64f01276-0XXX' named 'ssoaddins'. Send an
> interactive authorization request for this user and resource.\r\nTrace
> ID: 9a6a62f0-e698-48f3-ac77-ca18c0bbbd00\r\nCorrelation ID:
> 58843565-b171-4165-ab24-face78a43dfb\r\nTimestamp: 2023-03-15
> 01:23:42Z'

In the front end side I'm specifiying `allowConsentPrompt: true` but user does not get the consent screen. In which cases that happens ?

In Azure I defined the permission which are a deleguated ones, so no need for admin to approve.

[image]

I don't know why I get this error ?

Update after adapting my code I get a graph token that does not look as a valid token :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and added `API permissions` same as you like below:

[image]

Now I set Application ID URI and exposed an API named `access_as_user` like below:

[image]

When I tried to get access token using `on-behalf-of` flow with below parameters via Postman, I got **same error** as you like this:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope: User.Read access_as_user
grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion: assertion
requested_token_use: on_behalf_of
```

**Response:**
[image]

To **resolve** the error, try adding `access_as_user` in API permissions of application like this:

You can find that permission in **My APIs** as below:

[image]

Now, add  `access_as_user` in API permissions of application like this:

[image]

Make sure to grant **admin consent** for above added permissions as below:

[image]

If you generated **assertion** with `access_as_user` scope, then pass only Graph related permissions to get access token via **on behalf of** flow.

When I passed only `User.Read` permission in scope, I got access token successfully with **on-behalf-of flow** as below:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope: User.Read
grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion: assertion
requested_token_use: on_behalf_of
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, make sure to grant **admin consent** to all added permissions and pass **only** graph permissions like `User.Read` in scopes without joining  `access_as_user` while fetching token via **on-behalf-of** flow.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response , I was able to get the token by only enabling admin grant, I haven't needed to add `access_as_user` in API permissions, so I have é questions : 
1 )Why does it works without adding `access_as_user` in `myapi`section .
2) Why should admin grant, even when permissions are purely delegated ?

Comment: If you already selected `access_as_user` scope while adding **Authorized client applications** like [this](https://i.imgur.com/naJZ0A5.png), there is no need to add it separately in `MyAPI` section.

Comment: If your organization enabled either of these options like [1](https://i.imgur.com/IM43Uuh.png) and [2](https://i.imgur.com/OdQVGWb.png) to be more secure, **admin consent** is needed even when they are purely Delegated.